# Swift Best Pracices for compare a enum key to various key

Tags: swift, enums

```
enum GameBtnType {
    case keySelect
    case keyStart
    case keyBack
    case keyMore
    case keyA
}

if keyType == .keyA || keyType == .keyB || keyType == .keyStart{
...
}else{}
```

As Above snippet I want to compare one enum value to various key

Too much of || seems boring

Any Swifty way doing this ? : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
switch (keyType) {
   case .keyA,.keyB,.keyStart :
         //do something
   default :
         //do something else
}
```